# Webpack: CSS Order of Bundles with style-loader

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I have two entry points A and B in my webpack config.

Configuration for development looks like this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
},
```

Configuration for production looks like this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,  'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'],
},
```

Some Styles in Bundle B overwrite some styles in Bundle A. How can I make sure that in production all the Styles of A are loaded before B?

In production I can include B.css file after the A.css file and everything works fine. In development somehow the A styles are loaded after the B styles and therefore A styles overwrite B styles and not as expected the other way around.

How can I fix this?